# SQL Server Error 102 Incorrect Syntax near "

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

It's just telling me there is an error near ". Any help? Does that mean the problem is near a space? I've seen other people have similar problems with their error near '<' or ';' but not just ".

```
‍SELECT            CO.JCCo, CO.Contract, CO.PCO AS PCO, CO.PCOType, MAX(CO.COStatus) AS Status, MAX(CO.COApprovedYN) AS Approved, 
                                   SUM(CO.COContPendAmt) AS PriceAmount, 
                                   SUM(CO.COCostDollars) AS CostAmount,
                                   SUM(CO.COContPendAmt) - SUM(CO.COCostDollars) AS CO_Profit, 
                         PMOP.Description, PMOP.PendingStatus, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated) AS PODate, GETDATE() AS Today, DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated),                                            GETDATE()) AS DaysOutstanding, (CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) < 30 THEN 'Less than 30' 
                         WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 30 AND (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) <= 60 THEN ' 30 - 60 '                                    WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 60 AND (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) <= 90 THEN ' 60 - 90 ' 
                         WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 90 THEN ' Over 90 ' ELSE 'Less than 30' END) AS AgingCategory, 
                         PMOI.FixedAmount AS FixedAmount, PMOI.PendingAmount AS PendingAmount, PMOI.PCOItem,
                         (SELECT JCJM.ProjectMgr FROM JCJM WHERE JCJM.Job = CO.Contract AND JCJM.JCCo = 1) AS ProjectManager

FROM              brvJCCostRevChgOrders AS CO 
                                   RIGHT JOIN PMOP ON CO.PCOType = PMOP.PCOType AND CO.PCO = PMOP.PCO AND CO.Contract = PMOP.Contract 
                                   RIGHT JOIN PMOI ON PMOP.PCOType = PMOI.PCOType AND PMOP.PCO = PMOI.PCO AND PMOP.Project = PMOI.Project

WHERE            (PMOP.PendingStatus = 0) AND (CO.JCCo = 1) AND PMOP.Status <> 'VOID' AND PMOI.PMCo = 1 AND PMOP.PMCo = 1 AND (SELECT                                                        JCJM.ProjectMgr FROM JCJM WHERE JCJM.Job = CO.Contract AND JCJM.JCCo = 1) IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY      CO.JCCo, CO.Contract, CO.PCO, PMOP.Description, CO.PCOType, PMOP.PendingStatus, PMOI.PCOItem, PMOI.FixedAmount, PMOI.PendingAmount 

ORDER BY       CO.Contract, CO.PCOType
```

Comment: Incorrect Syntax near which line ? Can you give the whole error message ?

Comment: Only problem I see is you have a select in your where clause that could return multiple values and Exists should be used instead

Comment: It doesn't say which line. It's in Visual Studio. It literally just tells me Error 102, Incorrect Syntax near ".

Comment: When I copied your query to [rextester](http://rextester.com/TTSY86834) I saw a little red dot at the beginning (Probably some invisible char). Try to copy it without that little red dot back into your environment and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This part....

```
WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 30 AND (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) <= 60 THEN ' 30 - 60 '                                    WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 60 AND (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) <= 90 THEN ' 60 - 90 ' 
                         WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 90 THEN ' Over 90 ' ELSE 'Less than 30' END) AS AgingCategory,
```

is missing a `CASE` at the beginning and seemingly has a rouge parentheses at the end.

Here is the corrected version:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 30 AND (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) <= 60 
    THEN ' 30 - 60 ',                                    
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 60 AND (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) <= 90 
    THEN ' 60 - 90 ', 
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, MAX(PMOP.DateCreated), GETDATE())) > 90 
    THEN ' Over 90 ' 
    ELSE 'Less than 30' 
END AS AgingCategory,
```